# The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider libvirt and vagrant on Fedora 32

Tags: vagrant, kvm, libvirt

```sh
➜ sudo dnf install -y gcc libvirt libvirt-devel libxml2-devel make ruby-devel
➜ vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
➜ export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-libvirt-include=/usr/include/libvirt with-libvirt-lib=/usr/lib64"
➜ vagrant version                           
Installed Version: 2.2.9
```

And when I run it:

```
➜ vagrant init gusztavvargadr/docker-windows
➜ vagrant up --provider=libvirt
```

I get the following error

```
➜ vagrant up --provider=libvirt                                                                                    
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'libvirt' provider...
==> default: Box 'gusztavvargadr/docker-windows' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: libvirt
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'gusztavvargadr/docker-windows'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/gusztavvargadr/docker-windows
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: gusztavvargadr/docker-windows
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/gusztavvargadr/docker-windows
Requested provider: [:libvirt]
```

Comment: From the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: where is it declared as offtopic @Rob?

Comment: Hover over the vagrant tag.

Answer (score 0):

**solution:** is to use the upstream 
(not distro version or compressed version you get at Vagrant home page)

```sh
sudo dnf erase vagrant
_ dnf install https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.14/vagrant_2.2.14_x86_64.rpm

CONFIGURE_ARGS='with-ldflags=-L/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib with-libvirt-include=/usr/include/libvirt with-libvirt-lib=/usr/lib' \ 
  GEM_HOME=~/.vagrant.d/gems GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems  \
  PATH=/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin:$PATH \
  vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
```

output

```
nstalling the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching formatador-0.2.5.gem
Fetching fog-core-2.2.3.gem
Fetching fog-json-1.2.0.gem
Fetching mini_portile2-2.4.0.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.10.10.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Fetching fog-xml-0.1.3.gem
Fetching ruby-libvirt-0.7.1.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Fetching fog-libvirt-0.7.0.gem
Fetching vagrant-libvirt-0.3.0.gem
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-libvirt (0.3.0)'!
```